# Dataframe reshape for input into a LSTM model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Have collected the data and organized it like this:

One observation is organized into one dataframe

One dataframe is made up of 100 rows, in sequential order.

One row has 6 features and 1 label

How would I reshape this for a LSTM model... ?

```
my observation
            idx     prod   period   qty      label      
    0   Customer10  FG1    2483  200.000000   'A'   
    1   Customer11  FG2    2484  220.000000   'B'   
    2   Customer12  FG3    2485  240.000000   'C'
    3   Customer13  FG1    2485  240.000000   'C'
    ...
    100 Customer99  FG1    2485  240.000000   'A'
```

Comment: provide the minimal reproducible dataset and the piece of code you are working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to separate the data frame into x and y variables.

You can do this with a simple for loop, I don't know the specific data format so I can only give a boilerplate-like example.

```
x = []
y = []

for i in dataframe:
    if Is_Label:
        y.append(i)
    else:
        x.append(i)
```

Next you would need to convert the arrays into a numpy array. With numpy imported as `np` you would do.

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
```

With numpy you can use the `.reshape` method to reshape the data into your needs.

Comment: Thanks, But do you mean to do this: for example:  y[0] = 'outcome_1',  x[0] = [56,878,78,89].  or y[0] = 'outcome_1',  x[0] = 56, x[1] = 878....

Comment: Y would be the label in this case and X would be the values.
I wouldn't use strings as labels however, converting it into numbers using scaling or OHE would be better.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your question here is to do feature engineering on the dataset so that you can build a LSTM model or any other per say(your question on `reshaping` also comes under the bucket of feature engineering):

The prototype or basic procedure to be followed here seeing your data would be to:

1. Separate the independent(X) variables and dependent(y) variable
2. Convert the categorical variables to numerical using one-hot encoding or label encoding etc as per your choice, this will do all the heavy lifting for you
3. Do a test train split, this takes care of the shape issues as well

```
#split X and y
X, y=df.iloc[:, :-1], df.iloc[:, -1]

#label encode your 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
X[['idx', 'prod','period']] = le.fit_transform(X[['idx', 'prod','period']]) #however id or other columns can be dropped but its upto your EDA
y = le.fit_transform(y)

#split into test and train set and try running the model which you intend
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Then try running your model. You can always reshape your data as per your needs using `.reshape`